# R Find time difference in seconds for YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MMM format

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to subtract 2 character vectors containing date time information in the following format:

```
train2 <- data.frame(
  time2 = c(
    "2011-09-01 23:44:52.533", "2011-09-05 12:25:37.42", "2011-08-24 12:56:58.91",
    "2011-10-25 07:18:14.722", "2011-10-25 07:19:51.697"
  ),
  time3 = c(
    "2011-09-01 23:43:59.752", "2011-09-05 12:25:01.187",
    "2011-08-24 12:55:13.012", "2011-10-25 07:16:51.759",
    "2011-10-25 07:16:51.759"
  )
)
```

I've hunted around and played with `zoo`, `as.Date`, `as.POSIXct`, etc. to try and find the correct code to subtract 2 datetime objects and get an answer in seconds but without luck.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Easy peasy:

```
R> now <- Sys.time()
R> then <- Sys.time()
R> then - now
Time difference of 5.357 secs
R> class(then - now)
[1] "difftime"
R> as.numeric(then - now)
[1] 5.357
R>
```

And for your data:

```
R> df
                    time2                   time3
1 2011-09-01 23:44:52.533 2011-09-01 23:43:59.752
2  2011-09-05 12:25:37.42 2011-09-05 12:25:01.187
3  2011-08-24 12:56:58.91 2011-08-24 12:55:13.012
4 2011-10-25 07:18:14.722 2011-10-25 07:16:51.759
5 2011-10-25 07:19:51.697 2011-10-25 07:16:51.759
R> df$time2 <- strptime(df$time2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
R> df$time3 <- strptime(df$time3, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
R> df
                    time2                   time3
1 2011-09-01 23:44:52.533 2011-09-01 23:43:59.752
2 2011-09-05 12:25:37.420 2011-09-05 12:25:01.187
3 2011-08-24 12:56:58.910 2011-08-24 12:55:13.012
4 2011-10-25 07:18:14.722 2011-10-25 07:16:51.759
5 2011-10-25 07:19:51.697 2011-10-25 07:16:51.759
R> df$time2 - df$time3
Time differences in secs
[1]  52.781  36.233 105.898  82.963 179.938
attr(,"tzone")
[1] ""
R>
```

and added back as a numeric to the data frame:

```
R> df$dt <- as.numeric(df$time2 - df$time3)
R> df
                    time2                   time3      dt
1 2011-09-01 23:44:52.533 2011-09-01 23:43:59.752  52.781
2 2011-09-05 12:25:37.420 2011-09-05 12:25:01.187  36.233
3 2011-08-24 12:56:58.910 2011-08-24 12:55:13.012 105.898
4 2011-10-25 07:18:14.722 2011-10-25 07:16:51.759  82.963
5 2011-10-25 07:19:51.697 2011-10-25 07:16:51.759 179.938
R>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I would have never gotten that on my own.  Date-time stuff is a 'known unknown' for me (to borrow from Don Rumsfeld).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that you can force the time difference to be a particular unit of time using `difftime(then,now,units="secs")` or `difftime(then,now,units="mins")` etc... See `?difftime`

Comment: @screechOwl: As with many things R, it takes some head-scratching and forehead-banging at times but it is very, very powerful. Definitely worth learning.

Comment: This answer is potentially not correct. By default difftime objects have `units = "auto"` and are thus presented in the most suitable units (something like smallest unit such that unit is a consistent size and absolute differences are greater than one). `as.numeric` should use `units = "secs"`.

Comment: If time difference is big enough it will give a wrong answer. The answer below, includes the units... so this doesn't happen.

Comment: That was not part of the original question and dataset so I (somewhat strongly) disagree with the comment (and downvote).

Comment: The title of the question states "Find time difference in seconds..." so that is part of the original question. The answer given by andilabs is a better answer.

Comment: I've been bitten by `units = "auto"` badly in the past and I would strongly recommend to never ever subtracting times with `-`, especially if you're going to as.numeric() it  at the next step.

Answer (score 26):

```
>  x1<-"2013-03-03 23:26:46.315" 
>  x2<-"2013-03-03 23:31:53.091"
>  x1 <- strptime(x1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
>  x2 <- strptime(x2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
> x1
[1] "2013-03-03 23:26:46"
> x2
[1] "2013-03-03 23:31:53"
```

I followed the answer of @Dirk Eddelbuettel, but I am losing precision. How can I force R to not be cuting parts of second?

Thankfully (man of strptime) I answered my question myself:

```
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
```

After applying this setting the precision will be used.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html

The belowe may be useful if you would like to get difference in seconds, but get in minutes:

```
> as.numeric(x2-x1,units="secs")
[1] 306.776
```