# Whats the fastest way to find time diff

Tags: r, diff, timespan

Whats the fastest way in R to find time difference:
diff of row 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 and so on.
Or timespan from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, ...

In the end I heading for a function that shows all diffs/timspans e.g. > 7000ms

HH:MM:SS:MIS* *Milliseconds

`18:41:24.244
18:41:29.290
18:41:34.259
18:41:55.040
18:42:15.556
18:42:21.587
18:42:25.509
18:42:31.009
18:42:39.072
18:42:59.025
18:43:03.134
18:43:06.712
18:43:47.244
18:43:53.353
18:43:59.181
18:44:14.744
18:44:22.572
18:44:40.040
18:44:44.900
18:44:48.884
18:44:53.744
18:45:01.134
18:45:56.884
18:46:01.384
18:46:05.915
18:46:10.025
18:46:13.837
18:46:18.275
18:46:28.931
18:46:41.259
18:46:44.619
18:46:50.619`

Comment: You should find good hints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611361/r-find-time-difference-in-seconds-for-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-mmm-format, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649641/calculating-time-difference-in-r

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what format your data is in to start with. I've imported it as a character vector:

```
head(times)
# [1] "18:41:24.244" "18:41:29.290" "18:41:34.259" "18:41:55.040" ...
```

Then, since you want differences, we can just prepend an arbitrary date and convert to POSIXct

```
times <- as.POSIXct(paste("2014-01-01",times),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
diff(times)
# Time differences in secs
# [1]  5.046  4.969 20.781 20.516  6.031  3.922  5.500  8.063 19.953  4.109 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting with the character vector `x`

```
head(x)
# [1] "18:41:24.244" "18:41:29.290" "18:41:34.259" "18:41:55.040"
# [5] "18:42:15.556" "18:42:21.587"
```

You can use `strptime` with `diff`

```
st <- strptime(x, "%H:%M:%OS")
st[diff(st) > 7]
#  [1] "2014-11-02 18:41:34.259 PST" "2014-11-02 18:41:55.040 PST"
#  [3] "2014-11-02 18:42:31.009 PST" "2014-11-02 18:42:39.072 PST"
#  [5] "2014-11-02 18:43:06.712 PST" "2014-11-02 18:43:59.181 PST"
#  [7] "2014-11-02 18:44:14.744 PST" "2014-11-02 18:44:22.572 PST"
#  [9] "2014-11-02 18:44:53.744 PST" "2014-11-02 18:45:01.134 PST"
# [11] "2014-11-02 18:46:18.275 PST" "2014-11-02 18:46:28.931 PST"
```